# Как убрать _local из url для дефолтного языка

Tags: symfony, symfony3

подскажите пожалуйста.
Реализовал мультиязычность для сайта, но нужно убрать в урле приставку /en для дефолтного языка. Как это сделать?
Например есть урлы:

```
site.com/en/login -> site.com/login(убераеться _locale), 
site.com/fr/login -> site.com/fr/login(остаеться _locale)
```

Answer (score 1):

Я нашел решение которое мне подходит.Нужно установить бандл [JMSI18nRoutingBundle](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSI18nRoutingBundle/master/configuration)

Вот урок как настраивать сконфигурировать бандл. ([Сыылка на видео](https://codereviewvideos.com/course/getting-started-with-fosuserbundle/video/translations-and-internationalisation-in-fosuserbundle)) с 6-й минуты

```
jms_i18n_routing:
    default_locale: "%locale%"
    locales: [ru, ua]
    strategy: prefix_except_default (тут важно поставить именно такой параметр)
```